# with eclipse 3.5.2 - android sdk - where are the log files from a crash

Tags: android, eclipse, logging

I'm new to this android world and I'm finding that eclipse 3.5.2 is crashing constantly.  There is no real rhyme or reason that I can see.  Sometimes the crash occurs with the layout manager, sometimes when I try to search, other times when I attach a debugger.

I thought that there might be log files that could help me track down the problem.

Are there such things?

eclipse 3.5.2 with the latest android sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html

> Where is my Log?
>
> Eclipse has a log
> file where problems are recorded and
> usually this is the first thing that
> an Eclipse developer asks for when you
> report a problem. The log file can be
> found in a couple of places:
>
> Workspace log - This is the most
> common location for the log file, It
> is stored in your workspace in the
> meta-data directory. Check out
> workspace/.metadata/.log.
>
> Configuration log - Sometimes
> information is recored in the
> configuration log file instead of the
> workspace log. (especially if the
> workspace hasn't been created yet,
> there isn't one, or it cannot be
> created).
> Check your configuration area
> for a configuration log file.
> (configuration/.log)
>
> Startup - Occasionally problems happen
> in the system really early before
> there is a workspace and before there
> is a configuration area. This means
> that there is nowhere to write the log
> file so information is written to the
> console, See the notes below on
> running with a console to get these
> messages.

Comment: I for myself avoid Eclipse and already switched to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition (only Ultimate edition has Android support built-int), much nicer development experience and more stable; not free though, but you can test 30 days first. Also see my comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196013/ide-pros-and-cons-for-j2me-and-android-development/3201357#3201357

Answer (score 0):

Check your VM: Sun/Oracle's jre 1.6 update 21 crashes due to running out of Permgen space.  See [this explanation](http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2010/07/permgen-problems-and-running-eclipse-on.html).  This kind of crash may not generate any logs.

Answer (score 0):

I like checking the logs usings Dalvik Debug Monitor.  If the android-sdk is under your path,  you can type 'ddms' from your terminal to access it.  If it is not, go to < android-sdk >/toosl/ddms

Comment: this doesn't log anything Eclipse specific, only app specific. Using the layout manager in Eclipse is Eclipse/plugin specific though, therefore should be in the Eclipse logs.